# Clone assembly information

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, version

Currently I am using ResHacker to read and set assembly information. I am using my C# application to run ResHacker with proper command line arguments necessary for reading and setting the Assembly information. However, I would like to do this without a third party application.

I want to control the following:

```
File description:
Company Name:
File Version:
Date Created:
```

Comment: And you want to set it once for the whole solution, rather than in each of the projects' AssemblyInfo.cs?

Comment: @ Anders I want to read an executable's information, and then I want to be able to manually change an executable's information. (All through my C# app).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to edit the [VERSIONINFO resouce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058). To manipulate resources, you can use the resource functions:

- `FindResource`
- `LoadResource`
- `BeginUpdateResource`
- `UpdateResource`
- `EndUpdateResource`.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648008) for sample code (Win32 but shouldn't be too hard to convert to P/Invoke). The structure of the `VERSIONINFO` record itself is somewhat complicated and contains variable-length and nested records. Have a look at [this description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647001).

Comment: I'll need some time before I can look all of this information over today. I will +1 your suggestion though until I can confirm it's what I'm looking for. Thank you very much.